# jax ws generated client fails silently

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws

I prepared a spring web service using jax ws. It works fine and i can call this service from a number of other projects.

Interesting thing happened in another project. I tried to use this client again(by trying both by adding as source and just classes using a jar). When I call get end point port method on the service(before I can call the actual method on web service), it fails silently, there is no sign that the request is made to service, no exceptions caught. Only I have a finally clause on my controller, it does some calculations and quits(and prints a log).

Why does not this failure generate a general Exception? How can I trace the error else way? 
Or generally, what am i doing wrong?

usage:

```
logger.debug("web service: " + transferService.toString());                                                                          
            logger.debug("web service qname: " + transferService.getServiceName());                                                              
            logger.debug("web service url: " + transferService.getWSDLDocumentLocation());                                                       
            //logger.debug("web service endpoint: " + transferService.getTransferEndPointPort().toString());                                     

            QueryCardNumberWithIdWSResponse response =                                                                                           
                                transferService.getTransferEndPointPort().queryId(request);
```

transferService object functions normally until we call getTransferEndPointPort. It then crashes.

getTransferEndPoint implementation:

```
@WebEndpoint(name = "TransferEndPointPort")
    public TransferEndPoint getTransferEndPointPort() {
        loggerApache.debug("getting transfer end point ");
        loggerApache.debug("service name: " + super.getServiceName() );
        return super.getPort(new QName("http://www.blabla.com", "TransferEndPointPort"), TransferEndPoint.class);
    }
```

It prints the logs, but after super.getPort nothing happens, just the finally block in the controller works.

Edit: After a while i remembered to use Throwable in catch clauses. So I caught a throwable from the service eventually.

It was :

```
java error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.xml.ws.WebFault.messageName()Ljava/lang/String;
```

After searching the web, I concluded that I should not use WebFault in my web service because of java edition. I removed the throws exception from a web method (probably i forgot to remove it in earlier stages) and now it seems to be working.

Comment: Can you paste some code examples of this problem? Can it be a problem with your server configuration? What environment are you using? Are there any difference in this last project from the others? Are you sure that you are calling service which is working somewhere?

Comment: i have edited and added some usage. I am calling this web service from a spring application, and the web service is also a spring application itself.

Comment: An educated guess would be that you are using JAX-WS handler that is not behaving correctly

Comment: So you have a web service which is deployed on some url and is accessible, for example from a browser, yes? So in this project how do you create stubs for this web service? With `wsimport` or other way?

Comment: @SamiKorhonen how can i check that i am using a jax ws handler that is not behaving correctly?

Comment: i think i have used wsimport. i am using these stub classes in another  spring project. I also use them in a Play Framework app.

Comment: Disable all the handlers, if possible. It sounds like one of the handlers is returning false (blocks the execution) Check: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/ws/handler/Handler.html#handleMessage%28C%29

Comment: right now i have been using two other web service clients, and we have a web service of our own too. All of them use handlers. I think i cannot disable the handlers.